# how to create cove of top of Container and add image inside of CustomPainter in flutter app

Tags: flutter

how to add `image` inside of `CustomPainter` and manage.

like this:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hallo/appbar.dart';

class product1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              CustomPaint(
                size: Size.fromHeight(500),
                painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
              ),
              Container(

              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter  {

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {



    Paint paint0 = Paint()
      ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0;


    Path path0 = Path();
    path0.moveTo(0,0);
    path0.lineTo(0,size.height);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width*0.1120000,size.height*0.7968571,size.width*0.3375000,size.height*0.8585714);
    path0.cubicTo(size.width*0.5795625,size.height*0.9350714,size.width*0.8043750,size.height*1.0775000,size.width,size.height);
    path0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width,size.height*0.7500000,size.width,0);
    path0.lineTo(size.width*0.1252500,0);
    path0.lineTo(0,0);
    path0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path0, paint0);


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   const HomeScreen({
     super.key,
  });

static const String route = "/homeScreen";

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5,
          child: Image.network(
            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/14446269/pexels-photo-14446269.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: double.infinity,
          ),
        ),
        CustomPaint(
          size: MediaQuery.of(context).size,
          painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
}

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  Paint paint0 = Paint()
    ..color = const Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
    ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

  Path path1 = Path();
  path1.moveTo(0, size.height);
  path1.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.5);
  path1.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width * 0.1120000,
      size.height * 0.5 * 0.7968571,
      size.width * 0.3375000,
      size.height * 0.5 * 0.8585714);
  path1.cubicTo(
    size.width * 0.5795625,
    size.height * 0.5 * 0.9350714,
    size.width * 0.8043750,
    size.height * 0.5 * 1.0775000,
    size.width,
    size.height * 0.5,
  );
  path1.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
  path1.lineTo(0, size.height);
  path1.close();

  canvas.drawPath(path1, paint0);
}

@override
bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
  return true;
}
}
```

you will get this type of results:

[image]